# Build RSS Reader with HTML and PHP

Tags: php, rss

Could someone point me to a guide or some information on building a simple online rss reader. I've only been able to find guides on making rss feeds for your own site. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should it read contents from only one feed?

You might want to use simpleXML in case, here is a minimal example:

```
$url = $url_of_the_feed_in_question;
foreach(simplexml_load_file($url)->entry as $entry) {
  echo '<h2>'.$entry->title.'<h2>'.entry->content; 
}
```

For a more complete guide, take a look [here](http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/2007/01/07/using-simplexml-to-parse-rss-feeds/).

(BTW, try googling for "parser" instead of "reader")

Comment: By the way, would you mind accepting my answer - green check mark on the left?